# Netlify does not recognize the URL params when using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, netlify, netlify-cli

I am creating a react app that uses react router. I am using the router to match the paths like `:/bankName-:credit` and it works fine in local development. The only require path for my application is `:/bankName-:credit` and every other path will hit `404`.
But when I deploy this app to netlify then for default it goes to `/` and shows a custom `404`. That's all good. But now if I try to go to `/hdfc-500` then it gives a netlify not found message that `page not found`.

I tried using `_redirects` as mentioned in the [netlify docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#placeholders) but this does not work.

Here are my routes:-

App.js

```js
<Route path='/:bankCode-:credit' component={NestedRoutes} />
<Route component={NotFound} />
```

Here is my `NestedRoutes` component:-

```js
const NestedRoutes = ({ match }) => (
  <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress />}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/sc-generate`} component={SCGenerate} />
      <Route exact path='/:bankCode-:credit' component={Home} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
)
```

I am using following code in my `_redirects` file:-

```
/* /:bankCode-:credit
```

But it try to match exactly with `/:bankCode-:credit`

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recreated your problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-frost-ls353

The solution is simple, add a file called `_redirects` to your public folder with this content

```
/* /index.html 200
```

You can find more information on this link. https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/12/18/page-not-found-on-netlify-with-react-router/

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I was trying different redirects like but this one solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem while **passing url params in netlify** and got solved by removing the "."
before the href and src links in the **index.html** file inside the **build** folder.

**Hope this will help someone.**

Answer (score 0):

For Angular, this solution works for me
Add `_redirects` file in your src folder with the following line of code

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Then ensure you include the _redirects file in your angular.json assets array so that Angular will include a copy of the file when building your project:

```
"assets": [
  "src/_redirects"
]
```

You can find more info on this link https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/angular/

Answer (score 0):

One common solution that Netlify mentioned with their blog is structured configuration with `netlify.toml`

A. Create `netlify.toml` in your root directory

B. Add the following code that defines the custom redirect rules,

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

C. Deploy the file on Netlify along with your project.

Blog Reference:
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/