# Reactjs site doesn't load any sub pages other than homepage, hosted on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting, netlify

I hosted one of my website on **Netlify**. Site was built with **ReactJS**.

After deploying on Netlify, I can view the homepage but can't load any of the other pages.

Site works totally fine in localhost.

Is this a problem with routing?

I used `react-router` for routing.

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: Show your error

Comment: added the ss in the post just now.

Comment: can you add your `<Switch>` and `<Route>`s part?

Comment: found the solution here 

https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new file in your project public folder called `_redirects` then add this inside it

```
/* /index.html 200
```

its been solved here before [Netlify does not recognize the URL params when using react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468161/netlify-does-not-recognize-the-url-params-when-using-react-router-dom)

Comment: this worked. Also found this solution in this blog too.

https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @VimalPatel I did answer his question, the answer is basically that line

Answer (score 0):

Just found this blog post. This gives a good explanation.

Creating a file called `_redirects` in the public folder and adding this code

```
/* /index.html 200
```

solves the problem.

https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/page-not-found-error-on-netlify-reactjs-react-router-solved-43oa